# while is this while loop is not terminating when it hits the condition

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string str1,str2,str3;
    int val;
    char ch;
    cin>>val;
    while(val--){
        cin>>str1;
        str2=str1;
        reverse(str1.begin(),str1.end());

        for(int i=0;i<str1.size();i++){
             val=str1[i]-122+26;
             val+=str2[i]-122+26;
             val=val%26;
             ch=val+96;
              cout<<ch; 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Every ith character of string will be added to every ith character of reverse string.when i am trying to enter the value it produces infinite loop means the while loop is not hitting the condition. i am not able to find the reason.
any help is apperciated.

Comment: Please show us the input and expected output? Did you really intend to overwrite `val` in that `for`-loop?

Comment: While loop is false only when Val=0

Answer (score 2):

Because you reuse "val" without declaring it again.

There are two hard problems in computer science

- cache invalidation
- naming
- off by one error.

Yours is a variation of the 2nd. Reusing names where you should have made a new more describing for one of your two uses of "val".